# fill data to the database from comment form of post view in yii

Tags: php, yii

i have already the comment form bellow my post view , but the problem is that  it can not be store the data by comment form to the database which is bellow post view.
 My code for comment form....

```
<h5>Add your Comment</h5>

    <?php if(Yii::app()->user->hasFlash('commentSubmitted')): ?>
        <div class="flash-success">
            <?php echo Yii::app()->user->getFlash('commentSubmitted'); ?>
           <?php else: ?>
    <?php $comment= new Comment();
        $this->renderPartial('/comment/_form',array('model'=>$comment,
         )); ?>
```

and my code of _form is

```
<div class="form">

<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
  'id'=>'comment-form',
  'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
)); ?>

  <p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

  <?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>

  <div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'content'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textArea($model,'content',array('rows'=>6, 'cols'=>50)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'content'); ?>
  </div>
```

i want to store data from the comment form which is in the post view.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you are asking here, but I think you are asking how to save the data from the form submit? In you controller, in the action that renders the comment form, use:

```
$model = new Comment;
if(isset($_POST['Comment'])){
    $model->attributes=$_POST['Comment'];
    $model->save();
}
```

You should check out the gii tool (http://yiitutorials.net/easy/using-yiis-gii-tool), it will help you generate your models, forms and action to save the form data. Hope that answered your question, apologies if it didn't!

Answer (score 0):

On the downloaded source code you can find blog demo, and it has great example howto use comments :D